# android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnKeyListener

Tags: java, android

Could someone please explain why I am getting this error?

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to     android.view.View$OnKeyListener
```

Below is the java code.  I am trying to follow a tutorial and I can't get it started. The RAZR emulator only shows *`Unfortunately JimYamba quit working`*.  The error is from Eclipse LogCat.

```
package com.example.jimyamba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Log;;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button buttonUpdate;
EditText editStatus;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.status);

    buttonUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_update);
    editStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_status);

    buttonUpdate.setOnKeyListener((OnKeyListener) this.buttonUpdate);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v){
    String statusText = editStatus.getText().toString();
    Log.d("StatusActivity","onClicked with text:"  + statusText);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line `buttonUpdate.setOnKeyListener((OnKeyListener) this.buttonUpdate);`. Just as the error says, you cannot cast a button to an OnKeyListener. Explicit casting requires a relationship via class hierarchy - Button and OnKeyListener are not related (OnKeyListener is an interface).

If you want to maintain your set up you can create a class that extends Button and Implements OnKeyListener. You will have to edit you xml to have your custom view in place of the button.

Answer (score 1):

`buttonUpdate.setOnKeyListener((OnKeyListener) this.buttonUpdate);`

should be

```
buttonUpdate.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Comment: actually the problem was that SetOnKeyListener needed to be SetOnClickListener as inbuttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish? You have implemented OnClickListener so if all you need is to execute what's inside of the onClick method with an OnClickListener, just change

```
buttonUpdate.setOnKeyListener((OnKeyListener) this.buttonUpdate);
```

With

```
buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Or if you want OnKeyListener do what techiServices suggested

Comment: I'm fairly certain the question has been altered substantially, this answer is more fitting since the `Activity` is implementing the OnClickListener. +1

Comment: thanks to all  actually the problem was that SetOnKeyListener needed to be SetOnClickListener as inbuttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);